# Android setting facebook image url inside Feed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to search for an answer. I found a lot of answers about how to get image from the url.
My question is different.
I have url of the image:

```
String fbPhotoAddress = "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=" + idUploadResponse;
```

idUploadResponse is image id.

I want to put it inside Feed setPicture property.

```
// feed builder
final Feed feed = new Feed.Builder()
.setMessage("Write Comment...")
.setPicture(fbPhotoAddress).setLink("").build();
```

I don`t get the picture in the feed, but when I write the full link it works

```
 // feed builder
final Feed feed = new Feed.Builder()
.setMessage("Write Comment...")
.setPicture("https://scontent-a-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc3/t31.0-8/10333677_751771128207141_6465943630675929143_o.jpg").setLink("https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook").build();
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: I looked on: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/3/FB.Feed    
I read there, that .setPicture has to be PNG or JPG format. Any suggestions?